# Evaluating a single code block in two data frames in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames

```
d1 = data.frame(a=1:4,b=2:5)
d2 = data.frame(a=0:3,b=3:6)
```

and I would like to evaluate the same block of code, for example

```
  c<-exp(a)
  d<-b^2
```

within each data frame. At the moment I have to duplicate the code block as follows:

```
d1t = within(d1, {
  c<-exp(a)
  d<-b^2
})
d2t = within(d2, {
  c<-exp(a)
  d<-b^2
})
```

which makes my code prone to errors if I make changes to one of the code blocks (they should be the same).

I am not so familiar with environments in R, but I think it should be possible to use them to solve this problem nicely. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could place the dataframe objects in a `list`.  We search for the names of the objects with the pattern `^d\\d+` ie. 'd' followed by numbers in the global environment.  If there are multiple objects (in this case, 2 objects i.e. 'd1' and 'd2'), we can get the values using `mget` in a `list`.

```
 lst <- mget(ls(pattern='^d\\d+'))
```

Now, we loop through the `list` with `lapply` and create new variables 'c' and 'd' using `transform`.

```
 lst1 <- lapply(lst, transform, c=exp(a), d= b^2)
```

It is better to keep the 'data.frames' within the `list`.  But, if we need to update the original datasets or create new objects i.e. 'd1t' and 'd2t' (not recommended), we can change the names of the `list` elements with `setNames` and use `list2env` to create objects in the global environment.

```
 list2env(setNames(lst1, paste0(names(lst1), 't')), envir=.GlobalEnv)
 d1t
 #  a b         c  d
 #1 1 2  2.718282  4
 #2 2 3  7.389056  9
 #3 3 4 20.085537 16
 #4 4 5 54.598150 25

 d2t
 #  a b         c  d
 #1 0 3  1.000000  9
 #2 1 4  2.718282 16
 #3 2 5  7.389056 25
 #4 3 6 20.085537 36
```

Comment: @ShawnMehan It gives only the object names i.e. 'd1' and 'd2'.  To get the values, we need `get` or `mget`

Comment: Thanks, your original comment was actually more useful. I only have two data frames, constructed separately (so combining them into a list is unnecessary). But I have a very long code block, which includes function definitions. So `f=function(x)within(x,{x<-exp(a);d<-b^2}); d1t<-f(d1)` works best.

Comment: @js86 Thanks for the comment.  Yes, this is useful when you have multiple datasets.

Comment: @akrun Yep, agreed that's what mget will do, but do we need the value? I ran lapply(lst, transform, DOG=CAT) on two data frames found with ls(pattern...) and it found them and ran lapply with a positive result. The first param in lapply is simply looking for object names, no?

Comment: @ShawnMehan It is creating a new dataset instead of updating the original. For example `lst1 <- ls(pattern='^d\\d+$'); lapply(lst1, transform,DOG='CAT')
#[[1]]
  X_data DOG
1     d1 CAT`.  Here you can see that `d1` is a character string which is shown as the first column

Comment: @js86 Anyway, I think you need a `function`, but if you have multiple datasets, you have to run the function several times...

Answer (score 4):

This is the perfect situation to write the repeated code blocks into a function:

```
     MyFun <- function(df) {
        out = within(df, {
           c<-exp(a)
           d<-b^2
        })
        return(out)
      }
```

Will do it as long as the variable names are the same across datasets.

To run the code just do:

```
    d1t <- MyFun(d1)
    d2t <- MyFun(d2)
```

Should work.